# Immediate check of class' static side during implementation with Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm in the following situation, with two generic Queue interfaces: one for the instances side and the other for the static side of the classes that will implement the interface:

```
export interface Queue<T> {
  // instances stuff
}

export interface QueueConstructor<T> {
  new(arrayOfT?: Array<T>): Queue<T>;
  // static stuff
}
```

I'd like to check if an implementation correctly implement the static side, directly during the implementation phase. I do not want to use the first workaround presented [in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes), and the second one, because of generics, seems not usable.

Maybe there is a way to do that with decorators, but I'm not able to reach a proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are usable with the function that performs the check approach, ideally you should use generics to preserve any other members declared on the new class:

```
export interface Queue<T> {
  push(item: T): Queue<T>;
}

export interface QueueConstructor<T> {
  new(arrayOfT?: Array<T>): Queue<T>;

}

function checkQueue<T extends QueueConstructor<any>>(cls: T): T{
  return cls;
}

const myQueue = checkQueue(class <T> {
  constructor(public arrayOfT?: Array<T>) {

  }
  push(item: T): Queue<T>{
    return this;
  }
})

new myQueue<number>();

const myBadQueue = checkQueue(class <T> { // err
  constructor(length: number) {

  }
  push(item: T): Queue<T>{
    return this;
  }
})
```

This exact same function can also be used as a decorator and it will flag the same issues

```
function checkQueue<T extends QueueConstructor<any>>(cls: T): T{
    return cls;
}

@checkQueue
class myQueue<T> {
    constructor(public arrayOfT?: Array<T>) {

    }
    push(item: T): Queue<T>{
    return this;
    }
}

new myQueue<number>();

@checkQueue // err
class myBadQueue<T> { 
    constructor(length: number) {

    }
    push(item: T): Queue<T>{
    return this;
    }
}
```